# RxJS - Translating Observable of an Array to a new Observable of an Array

Tags: arrays, rxjs, observable

I have an oberservable, which is an array:

`items$: Observable<CarClassification[]>;`

And I am trying to translate/convert this into a new Observable of an array of *SelectItems* for a dropdown box.

`get SelectItems(): Observable<SelectItem[]> { ...`

Which I can then set as the datasource for the dropdown box, and, if any item in *items$* is modified, deleted or a new one added, the array of *SelectItems* changes as wel. The issue I am having is that I have dozens of these arrays (criteria for a larger object) that need to be defined in this way. Everything I have tried to date, if it works, is just too slow (subscribing to the observable and pushing to a new array) and I am looking for a more seamless way.

I'm new to RxJS, and I have tried a few different things, but none seem to work. I've search as much StackOverflow as I think I ever have.

CarClassification has two properties, **Id** and **Name** that I want to make the **value** and **label** of the *SelectItem*.

I know I can map the observable to an array:

`items$.map((items) => { ...`

But how to then properly iterate over each *item* in *items*, and return a new *SelectItem* for each has been eluding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an Observable that emits arrays you can always unpack it with `concatAll()` and then pack it again like for example this:

```
Observable.of([{...}, {...}, {...}])
  .concatAll() // unpack
  // will emit each {...} as a single value
  .toArray() // pack
```

But you don't need to use Rx to transform the array at all:

```
items$.map((items: CarClassification[]) => {
  return items.map((item: CarClassification) => new SelectItem(...));
});
```

Now you have `Observable<SelectItem[]>`.